# Sending results from different machines with the same runners

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

We have the problem with sending C# scan results to SonarQube. Sonarqube doesn't receive some issues as **S1541 "Methods are too complex"** (The cyclomatic complexity of a function should not exceed a defined threshold). Our sonar-runner runs from Jenkins Job. If we run this job from Windows Server 2008 R2, Sonarqube receives these issues

[image: 2008R2]

if we run the same job from Windows Server 2012 R2 Sonarqube doesn't receive them

[image: 2012R2]

SonarQube v5.5

Comment: which scanners do you use and in which verisons? is the configuration on both servers definitly the same?

Comment: MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.1. Configuration is the same